# Meisenheimer complex in Preparation of 2-Naphthol from 2-Naphthalenesulfonic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, resonance

I'm trying to figure out the *addition-elimination mechanism* for the preparation of **2-naphthol** from **2-naphthalenesulfonic acid**. I know that the **$\ce{SO3^2-}$** group is functioning as the leaving group, but I don't know how to draw the Meisenheimer complex.

I also can't find anything on the internet about the Meisenheimer complex of naphthalene, I tried to draw it, but this became too hard for me as there were too many resonance structures. Can someone please help?

[image]